# How to implement pagination and total with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have not found  how to return total data included in the resultset. Is there any way to return total data? I need to confirm that the correct JSON data is returned.

#### What I want is to have something like this returned:

```
total: 40,
page: 1,
pageSize: 3,
books: [
{
    _id: 1,
    title: "达·芬奇密码 ",
    author: "[美] 丹·布朗",
},
{
   _id: 2,
   title: "梦里花落知多少",
   author: "郭敬明",
 },
 {
    _id: 3,
    title: "红楼梦",
    author: "[清] 曹雪芹",
   }
 ]
}
```

#### Current code:

```
router.get('/booksquery', (req, res) => {

var page = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1;
var limit = parseInt(req.query.limit) || 3;

Book.find({})
    .sort({ update_at: -1 })
    .skip((page-1) * limit)
    .limit(limit)
    .exec((err, doc) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err)
        } else {
            res.json({
                total: doc.total,
                page: page,
                pageSize: limit,
                books:doc,
            });
        }
    })
 })
```

Comment: probably if current page index is `0` default and pagination starts with next page, that is `1`, your could do `.skip(page * limit)`  make sure `.skip()` and `.limit()` gets Number.

Comment: Ok, but how to return total data?

Comment: added answer, once ceck it out

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Probably you could do something like this:

> Only if current page index is 0 default and pagination starts with next page, that is 1, your could do .skip(page * limit) make sure .skip() and .limit() gets Number.

```
  router.get("/booksquery", (req, res) => {
  var page = parseInt(req.query.page) || 0; //for next page pass 1 here
  var limit = parseInt(req.query.limit) || 3;
  var query = {};
  Book.find(query)
    .sort({ update_at: -1 })
    .skip(page * limit) //Notice here
    .limit(limit)
    .exec((err, doc) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.json(err);
      }
      Book.countDocuments(query).exec((count_error, count) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.json(count_error);
        }
        return res.json({
          total: count,
          page: page,
          pageSize: doc.length,
          books: doc
        });
      });
    });
});
```

from above you will get response like below:

```
 {
  books: [
    {
      _id: 1,
      title: "达·芬奇密码 ",
      author: "[美] 丹·布朗"
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      title: "梦里花落知多少",
      author: "郭敬明"
    },
    {
      _id: 3,
      title: "红楼梦",
      author: "[清] 曹雪芹"
    }
  ],
  total: 3,
  page: 0,
  pageSize: 3
}
```

if you use any condition and over that you want to make query and get result and total on that basics. do it inside `var query ={}` .
and the same query will be used for `.count()` also.
so you can get `total` **count** on the basics of that condition.

Comment: `count` is deprecated. Use `countDocuments` or `estimateCountDocuments` if it is a big set. [Mongoose count](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.count)

Answer (score 4):

In case someone wants to see this using **async/await** in 2020, and some random query instead of an empty object. Remember that `estimatedDocumentCount` does not work using query filters, it needs to be `countDocuments` by using the query on it. Please check:

```
  const { userId, page, limit } = req.headers;

  const query = {
    creator: userId,
    status: {
      $nin: ['deleted'],
    },
  };



  const page_ = parseInt(page, 10) || 0;

  const limit_ = parseInt(limit, 10) || 12;

  const books = await BookModel.find(query)
    .sort({ update_at: -1 })
    .skip(page_ * limit_)
    .limit(limit_);

  const count = await BookModel.countDocuments(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

`count()` is deprecated(form mongoose@5.x). `estimatedDocumentCount()` is faster than using `countDocuments()` for large collections because `estimatedDocumentCount()` uses collection metadata rather than scanning the entire collection.
Reference: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.estimatedDocumentCount

So the code is perfect just replace **countDocuments** to **estimatedDocumentCount**

```
router.get("/booksquery", (req, res) => {
  var page = parseInt(req.query.page) || 0; //for next page pass 1 here
  var limit = parseInt(req.query.limit) || 3;
  var query = {};
  Book.find(query)
    .sort({ update_at: -1 })
    .skip(page * limit) //Notice here
    .limit(limit)
    .exec((err, doc) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.json(err);
      }
      Book.estimatedDocumentCount(query).exec((count_error, count) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.json(count_error);
        }
        return res.json({
          total: count,
          page: page,
          pageSize: doc.length,
          books: doc
        });
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: estimatedDocumentCount will ignore the  query object and always return the total number of documents. Go with countDocuments if you are using custom query.